# What kind of current division is this

Tags: capacitor, current

[image: --]

Can you explain why it is 6 * (3/9) ,Why don't we add 5kΩ resistance too,
How is this a current division,what is the formula for this.Thanks..

Comment: Isn't the 5k resistor disconnected in your 2nd diagram?

Comment: How is it disconnected  ?

Comment: Not "how" but "is".

Comment: For DC current the 5K resistor will effectively be disconnected. But what is it you're trying to calculate?

Comment: @Andyaka, the 2nd diagram is showing the same circuit as the first diagram but with the capacitors replaced by opens.

Comment: Yes I know but I’m trying to get the op to think about this and get him to reason out why. It’s an exact duplicate anyway!